# how to remove a node from a linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to perform a binary operation between two nodes, store the result in one node and eliminate the other. This is what I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

    struct n{
        double value;
        char op;
        struct n *next;
    };

    void delete(struct n *head);
    void add_item(struct n **ptr, double *data);

    int main(){
        struct n *head = NULL;
        double result;
        add_item(&head, 5);
        add_item(&head, 3);
        head->op = '*';
        result = (head->next)->value * head->value;
        (head->next)->value = result;
        delete(head);
        printf("%lf\n",head->value);
        free(head); 
        return 0;        
    }

    void add_item(struct n **ptr, double *data)
    {
            struct n *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

            item->value = *data;
            item->next = *ptr;
            item->op = '?';
            *ptr = item;
    }

    void delete(struct n *head)
    {
        struct n *temp;
        temp = head->next;
        head->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
```

In this example I have a list like this `3 -> 5 -> NUll`. I'd like to get this `15 -> NUll`. 
When I try to print the value of the node remaining I get `3` instead of `15`

Comment: The code you show is *close* to a [mcve] but not really close enough. What is `head`? What header files do you include?

Comment: And think about what happens when you do `(head->next)->value = result;` directly followed by `delete(head)` which unconditionally deletes the *second* node in the list.

Comment: The way I would solve your problem is to create a function which *remove* (but not delete) the "head" node from the list, and returns it. Then you can remove the head twice to get their values, perform the operation you want, and add a new node with the result. Treating the list as a stack (with push and pop operations).

Comment: Your 'delete' doesn't change the value of head.  It's still pointing to the same element that you intended to delete.

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `void delete(struct n **head) {struct n *tmp; tmp=(*head)->next; free(*head) ;*head=tmp;}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I've forgotten `head->next = temp->next;` But am I really freeing the location occupied by the second node? I mean Is there a way to discard all its content?

Answer (score 3):

The both functions are invalid.

To the function `add_item` you do not pass data by reference (and it does not make sense to pass data by reference).

```
    add_item(&head, 5);
    add_item(&head, 3);
```

So the function should be declared and defined like

```
void add_item(struct n **ptr, double data)
{
        struct n *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

        item->value = data;
        item->next = *ptr;
        item->op = '?';
        *ptr = item;
}
```

You have to pass the head node to the function `delete` also by reference.

```
void delete(struct n **head)
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        struct n *temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
delete( &head );
```

> When I try to print the value of the node remaining I get 3 instead of
>   15

It is because you deleted the node after the head instead of deleting the head node though the result of the operation you wrote in the node after the head.

```
(head->next)->value = result;
```

Here is your updated program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    struct n{
        double value;
        char op;
        struct n *next;
    };

    void delete(struct n **head);
    void add_item(struct n **ptr, double data);

    int main(){
        struct n *head = NULL;
        double result;
        add_item(&head, 5);
        add_item(&head, 3);
        head->op = '*';
        result = (head->next)->value * head->value;
        (head->next)->value = result;
        delete(&head);
        printf("%lf\n",head->value);
        free(head); 
        return 0;        
    }

void add_item(struct n **ptr, double data)
{
        struct n *item = malloc(sizeof *item);

        item->value = data;
        item->next = *ptr;
        item->op = '?';
        *ptr = item;
}

void delete(struct n **head)
{
    if ( *head )
    {
        struct n *temp = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
15.000000
```

Comment: I get `error: invalid initializer  struct n temp = *head;`

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci Did you pass the head as I showed delete( &head ); and declared the parameter like struct n **head?

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci Oh, I am sorry. There was a typo. Must be struct n *temp = *head; within the function.

Comment: I get `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci Show all statements where you called delete in main and free in main.

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci Can you just copy and paste the code I showed or is it  so difficult?

Answer (score 3):

As is in general with C, for a function to have the power to change an object passed to it via the argument list, the *address of* the object must be passed, not the object itself. ( *[read more on this here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74-passing-arguments-by-address/)* )

In this example, the object, `head`,  if it is to be changed in any way, requires that its *address* ( `&head` ) be passed to the function, not the object itself.
So the statement:

```
delete(head); //passing the object will not allow it to be changed
```

Should be changed to

```
delete(&head); //The object's address is passed, allowing the object to be changed
```

And because the object being passed was created as a pointer: `struct n *head = NULL;`, the prototype for the `delete` function needs to accommodate the *address of* a pointer in its argument.  This is done with a pointer to a pointer:

```
void delete(struct n **head);//accommodates the address of a pointer object
```

Then, inside the `delete` function, work on the object itself, (which is now `*head`) to make the changes.

```
   void delete(struct n **head)
    {
        if (*head == NULL) return;
        struct n *temp = *head;
        *head = temp->next;//point head to next node
        free(temp);//free old head
    }
```

Conversely, in your `void add_item(struct n **ptr, double *data);` function, `data` does not need to be changed, only used within the body.  Indeed the way it has been called in your code is the correct way to send the data:

```
add_item(&head, 5);  // 2nd argument passes object directly, i.e. not an address
```

Therefore, because the function needs the data itself, and not a pointer to the data, change the prototype to accommodate:

```
void add_item(struct n **ptr, double data);
```

Change the code in the body of the code accordingly.